# Join tables with composite keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got two tables, in which both id_health_center and id_user are used as composite key:

- health_center_review

  - id_health_center
  - id_user
  - review
- health_center_grade

  - id_health_center
  - id_user
  - grade_service

I would like to build a query that would return reviews from health_center_review with grades given by the same user. For example:

```
id_health_center | id_user | review
---------------------------------------
1                | 1       | something 1
1                | 2       | something 2

id_health_center | id_user | grade_service
-------------------------------------------
1                | 1       | 5
```

would return:

```
id_user | review       | grade_service
----------------------------------------------------
1       | something 1  | 5
2       | something 2  | NULL
```

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT hcr.id_user, review, grade_service
FROM health_center_reviews hcr
LEFT JOIN health_center_grades hcg ON hcg.id_health_center = hcr.id_health_center AND hcg.id_user = hcr.id_user
WHERE hcr.id_health_center = 1;
```

hovewer that only returns reviews if they have grades. If I omit the user part in join clause, it returns the grade for other user.

Comment: Your query should be doing what you want.  I note that the results do not fit the data/query, because there is no `grade_service` with a value of "1".  The behavior suggests that the actual `where` clause you are using is `hcg.id_health_center = 1`.

Comment: Yes, you were right - it was wrong where table. Thank you ;)

Comment: What does the query return?